# From normalized Pandas DataFrame to list of nested dicts

Tags: python, pandas

Supposing I have obtained a normalized DataFrame starting from a list of nested dicts:

```
sample_list_of_dicts = [
    { 'group1': { 'item1': 'value1', 'item2': 'value2' } },
    { 'group1': { 'item1': 'value3', 'item2': 'value4' } }
]

df = pd.json_normalize(sample_list_of_dicts)
```

Is there a way to revert back to the list of nested dicts from the DataFrame `df`?

Comment: Is there always be the same group name `'group1'` in the list ?

Comment: The general problem have no solution, because mutiple nested dicts can be mapped to the same output. You need to provide additional info about the structure of your data, for example like the previous question made by @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I would like to build the nested structure leveraging the dot "." in the columns names. This would be sufficient to generalize the task

Comment: @espogian, so will the parent key `'group<num>'` always be unique in your application?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a 2-line code to do this -

```
#Expand columns to multi-index
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)

#Iterate the highest level and convert records to dict
output = [{k:j} for k in df.columns.levels[0] for j in df[k].to_dict('records')]
output
```

```
[{'group1': {'item1': 'value1', 'item2': 'value2'}},
 {'group1': {'item1': 'value3', 'item2': 'value4'}}]
```

#### Explanation

1. Converting the normalized json format (with columns of a.b format) to multi-index will help filter the data frame for records belonging to different groups.
2. Once converted, you can iterate over the highest-level groups and fetch the records as jsons.
3. Then you can iterate over each record and add it as a value for the corresponding group as a dict in a list comprehension.

Comment: This is my favorite solution, I've accepted it because it seems simpler that the one from @RomanPerekhrest. I have a question though: what if the original list of dicts has more than one level (group, in my example) inside?

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible approaches is to indexing with unique group names, renaming and collapsing columns with further transformations.
Yet it's a bit lengthy solution (as for me), and I'd be glad to see if someone could achieve a shorter *pandas* way to same final result.

```
sample_list_of_dicts = [
    {'group1': {'item1': 'value1', 'item2': 'value2'}},
    {'group2': {'item1': 'value3', 'item2': 'value4'}}
]
df = pd.json_normalize(sample_list_of_dicts)

# set index with unique 'group' prefixes
df.set_index(df.columns.str.replace(r'\..*', '', regex=True).unique(), inplace=True)
# rename column names to those going after 'group<digit>.'
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'group\d+\.', '', regex=True)
# collapse identical column names horizontally and transpose the df
df_dict = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum().T.to_dict()
# recompose final dict into a list of dicts
lst = list(map(dict, zip(df_dict.items())))

print(lst)
```

The output:

```
[{'group1': {'item1': 'value1', 'item2': 'value2'}},
 {'group2': {'item1': 'value3', 'item2': 'value4'}}]
```

---

This can be also chained in a single pipe:

```
df_dict = df.set_index(df.columns.str.replace(r'\..*', '', regex=True).unique())\
    .set_axis(df.columns.str.replace(r'group\d+\.', '', regex=True), axis=1)\
    .pipe(lambda df_: df_.groupby(df_.columns, axis=1).sum()).T.to_dict()
lst = list(map(dict, zip(df_dict.items())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another short solution using *"**expand** (column names) -> **stack** (from columns to index) -> **transpose**"* chain:

```
df_dict = df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True), axis=1)\
    .stack(0).droplevel(0).T.to_dict()
lst = list(map(dict, zip(df_dict.items())))
```

The `lst` contents:

```
[{'group1': {'item1': 'value1', 'item2': 'value2'}},
 {'group2': {'item1': 'value3', 'item2': 'value4'}}]
```